# Shaping numpy 2D array based on another 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have `(n,m)` array `arr1`, where `n` is almost 2.5 million and `m =100`. Another `arr2` is `(n, 1)`. 
I want to modify `arr1` such that:

```
arr1[i, j] = arr1[i, j], if j <= arr2[i]
           = nan       , otherwise
```

Sample `arr1` and `arr2` are as follows (note `arr1` can be float too while `arr2` is always int):

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.random.randint(500, size=(4,3))
arr1
    array([[147,  46, 168],
           [232, 446, 415],
           [ 21, 245, 214],
           [246, 194, 271]])
arr2 = np.random.randint(4, size=(4,))
arr2
    array([3, 0, 2, 1])
```

Desired output in this case would be:

```
array([[147,  46, 168],
       [nan, nan, nan],
       [ 21, 245, nan],
       [246, nan, nan]])
```

Realistic sample to try for speed is

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.random.randint(500, size=(2500000, 100))
arr2 = np.random.randint(101, size=(2500000,))
```

Comment: So `arr2` is an array of *integers*?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes but `arr1` can be float too.

Comment: shouldn't be the random range for `arr2` be 100 instead of 100? Otherwise, we would get an out-of-range error, right?

Comment: @RolandDeschain I am assuming index start from 1 and not 0. But if assuming from 0 then yes 100 instead of 101

Comment: @Gerry Python is 0-based indexed. So you want 100 instead of 101

Comment: @Ehsan I know Python is 0-based. I didn't answer Roland well. I am using 0 for   everything being `nan` and row-len for all the values being taken from the row. Perhaps it would be clear by looking at the 4X3 matrix example I gave in question above why I used 4 and not 3 for `arr2`. Also the answer below works well with 4 and not 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example:
`arr2[:,None] <= list(range(3))` will give you a boolean array indicating the list of elements that need to be replaced by nan.

So

```
mask = arr2[:,None] <= list(range(arr1.shape[1]))
result = arr1.astype(float)
result[mask] = np.nan
```